# What is com.apple.FinderInfo in `ls -l@` at Home?

Tags: macos, 32-bit, data-structures

I run

```
~ master $ ls -l@
```

I get

```
total 3
drwx------+ 41 Masi  staff   1.4K Jul 18 03:20 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x@ 18 Masi  staff   612B Jul 14 10:41 Dropbox
        com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
drwx------+ 54 Masi  staff   1.8K Jul  4 20:35 Library
```

com.apple.FinderInfo seems to [be some data-structure](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/FSMegaInfo/listing17.html).

`ls`' option @ should display only

> Display extended attribute keys and
>   sizes.

However, it [displays a row with 32B](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=97984) which suggests me that it is a data-structure such as

```
0000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00    ................
0010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
```

I would like to know why the `ls -l@` shows the data structure.

**Why does the `ls -l@` shows the data structure at my Home?**

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to SuperUser?

Comment: how did you display the bytes like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an extended attribute. "com.apple.FinderInfo" is the key, and that binary data is the value.

Comment: Why does the folder Dropbox need that?

Comment: I know that you cannot make forks in the folder Dropbox. This may be related to that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The com.apple.FinderInfo line is referring to the previous line's file, ie: Dropbox.